# как добавить json(информацию) внутрь?

Tags: javascript, json

есть json file:

```
{
    "match_1": {
        "creator": 1,
        "fighter": 2,
        "bet": 100,
        "time": 10
    },

    "match_2":  {
        "creator": 1,
        "fighter": 2,
        "bet": 100,
        "time": 10
    }
  
}
```

при добавлении нового блока он съезжает с него

```
{
    "match_1": {
        "creator": 1,
        "fighter": 2,
        "bet": 100,
        "time": 10
    },

    "match_2":  {
        "creator": 1,
        "fighter": 2,
        "bet": 100,
        "time": 10
    }
  
}
{
  "match_3": {
    "creator": 1,
    "fighter": 2,
    "bet": 100,
    "time": 10
  }
}
```

как исправить это?
js:

```
const fs = require("fs");



let match = { 
    match_3:  {   
        creator: 1,
        fighter: 2,
        bet: 100,
        time: 10,
    }

};

match= JSON.stringify(match, null, 2)

fs.appendFile('users.json', match, aa);




function aa(err) {
    console.log("1")

}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HrjC6RwEpt0 , здесь подробно

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```js
let obj = {
    "match_1": {
        "creator": 1,
        "fighter": 2,
        "bet": 100,
        "time": 10
    },

    "match_2":  {
        "creator": 1,
        "fighter": 2,
        "bet": 100,
        "time": 10
    }
  
};

let additional =  {
  "match_3": {
    "creator": 1,
    "fighter": 2,
    "bet": 100,
    "time": 10
  }
}

let result = Object.assign(obj, additional);

console.log(result);
```